# WPF Printing large custom control

Tags: wpf, printing, xpsdocument, visual-tree, documentpaginator

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything relating to it.

I'm trying to create an XpsDocument from a custom control that I have. The custom control already defines properties for a header and a footer, along with the body.

The idea is to be able to use that same control (or derivatives of it) as an input to some custom DocumentPaginator that will create a printer-ready version of that "report", with the header and the footer put on every page, and the controls, inside the body, showing in full (I don't want to create a bitmap of the whole control, then scale it and cut it where the page ends).

Any ideas on how I can split the contents of a user control into pages?
Or suggestions on a different way to achieve the printing of the control onto pages?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check of VisualDOcumentPaginator; 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164033/WPF-Visual-Print-Component

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, ChrisDD!
It is the closest to what I want so far.
It doesn't split the visual, based on the controls (meaning: you get controls just cut through the middle at the end of the page), but this will be the only thing left to work on.